# Can $F(t) \cdot \int_{0}^{1} f(x) a(x) dx - \int_{0}^{t} f(x) a(x) dx$ be negative?

Tags: probability, density-function

I have the following expression

$$F(t) \cdot \int_{0}^{1} f(x) a(x) dx - \int_{0}^{t}  f(x) a(x) dx.$$

$f(x)$ is a density function with $f(x) > 0$ if $x \in [0,1]$ and $f(x)=0$ otherwise. $a(x)$ is a monotoneously increasing function with $a(0) = 0$ and $a(1)=1$. Between 0 and 1, $a(x)$ is either strictly convex, strictly concave, or linear. And $0<t<1$.

I would like to know if/when this expression becomes negative. I haven't been able to find a numerical example where it does become negative and I feel that if $a(x)$ is concave, it could happen, but I would like proof either way. I tried integration by parts, but that didn't get me anywhere.

*Edit*: F(x) is the CDF of f(x) only. No weight is applied here.

*Edit2*: The second integral goes from 0 to t, not 0 to 1 (I guess it's easy to overlook with 1 and t being fairly similar).

*Edit3*: a(x) is continuous and differentiable.

Comment: As written, it doesn't depend on $f$ or $a$ at all (beyond the fact that their integrals are strictly positive). It only matters if $F<1$ which it seems like it is if it is a CDF, so this expression should always be negative.

Comment: Yes, F(x) is the CDF. But did you notice that the second integral goes from 0 to t, not 0 to 1 as the first one? If both were from 0 to 1, I agree it would obviously be negative, but I don't think it's obvious (at least not to me) if the second one goes from 0 to t.

Comment: Is $F(t) = \int_0^t f(x)a(x)\,dx$? Or is it without the weight function $a$ *a la* $F(t) = \int_0^t f(x)\,dx$? The answer depends on this information.

Comment: @CameronWilliams, OP writes $F(x)$ is the CDF corresponding to pdf $f(x)$.

Comment: @dfnu Yes, but that doesn't mean that there isn't an associated weight function which is why I asked. It is very common to have CDFs that are of the form $\int_0^t f(x)w(x)\,dx$ where $w > 0$ is a weight function. This is of course equivalent to a different choice in measure (i.e. $d\mu(x) = w(x)\,dx$ by Radon-Nikodym).

Comment: $F(t)$ is indeed just $\int_0^t f(x)$, the weight is not applied.

Comment: @CameronWilliams ops, yes you're correct of course.

Comment: @dfnu: Did you remove your previous answer because of the unclear weight question? It looked correct to me at first sight given that there is indeed no weight on $F(t)$.

Comment: @BJU, I uncorreclty assumed $a(x)$ to be continuous, which might not be the case... I can re-post it so that someone can find some mistakes on the procedure and produce a more general statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I leave my answer, even though what follows is correct - I think - only if $a(x)$ is continuous.

---

Let

$$g(t) = F(t) \int_0^1 f(x)a(x)dx - \int_0^t f(x)a(x) dx,$$

continuous and differentiable in $\Bbb R$. Since, according to your hypotheses, $F(0) = 0$ and $F(1)=1$, you have

$$g(0) = 0$$
and
$$g(1) = 0.$$

Also,
\begin{eqnarray}
g'(t) &=& f(t) \int_0^1 f(x)a(x)dx - f(t)a(t) =\\
&=& f(t) \left[\int_0^1 f(x)a(x)dx - a(t)\right].
\end{eqnarray}
Since $a(x)$ is injective, and $0<\int_0^1 f(x) a(x)dx\leq1$, there is *exactly one value* $0<\overline t< 1$ such that
$g'(\overline t) = 0$, that is the value for which
$$a(\overline t) = \int_0^1 f(x)a(x) dx.$$

Thus $g(t) \neq 0$, for $t\in (0,1)$, because otherwise we would have a contradiction to Rolle's Theorem.

Furthermore, $g'(t) >0$ when $a(t) < \int_0^1 f(x)a(x)dx$, that is for $0 <t<\overline t$.

In conclusion, $g(t)>0$ when $t\in (0,1)$.

Comment: In my problem, $a(x)$ is indeed continuous.

Comment: @BJU ok, then. I think that should be correct. Since $a(x)$ *is* injective.